# Phonegap Plugin Barcodescanner Build not working

Tags: android, xml, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I am trying to use the barcodescanner plugin in phonegap, but whenever I try "phonegap build android", I get an error. The error is:

> BUILD FAILED in 2s
>   cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   D:\Projects\Mobile_Apps\apps\inventory-manager\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml:66: AAPT: error: unbound prefix.
>
> D:\Projects\Mobile_Apps\apps\inventory-manager\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml:66: error: unbound prefix.
>   D:\Projects\Mobile_Apps\apps\inventory-manager\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml: error: file failed to compile.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

I added the following code to my config.xml file (as the plugin instructions said to do):

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*" mode="merge">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
</config-file>
```

And I think this is the crux of the problem but I'm not sure what's wrong or how to fix it because if I take it out, the app crashes.

Here is what the config.xml file (located in the root folder of the project) looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>helloworld</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.2.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.5" />
    <platform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*" mode="merge">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    </config-file>
        <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="http://code.jquery.com/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://api.upcitemdb.com/*" />
        <access origin="https://api.upcitemdb.com/*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="wp8">
        <icon height="99" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" />
        <icon height="159" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/Background.png" width="159" />
        <splash height="1280" platform="wp8" src="www/res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" width="768" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="windows">
        <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
        <icon height="30" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
        <icon height="50" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
        <splash height="300" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
        <icon height="120" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="44" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
        <icon height="106" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
        <icon height="70" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
        <icon height="71" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
        <icon height="170" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
        <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
        <icon height="310" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
        <splash height="1920" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
    </platform>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="com.manateeworks.barcodescanner" spec="1.8.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-http" spec="2.1.1">
        <variable name="OKHTTP_VERSION" value="3.10.0" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="android" spec="7.1.4" />
</widget>
```

The config file referenced in the error looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="MWBarcodeScanner">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.manateeworks.BarcodeScannerPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <allow-navigation href="cdvfile:*" />
    <feature name="CordovaHttpPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.silkimen.cordovahttp.CordovaHttpPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.batterystatus.BatteryListener" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.Geolocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.globalization.Globalization" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Vibration">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.vibration.Vibration" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="BarcodeScanner">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" />
    </feature>
    <name>helloworld</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <config-file mode="merge" parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    </config-file>
    <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://code.jquery.com/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://api.upcitemdb.com/*" />
    <access origin="https://api.upcitemdb.com/*" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
</widget>
```

Any help would be so much appreciated!! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I just needed to delete my old android build, remove the code I added to the XML file, and rebuild the app! However, when I launch the app and attempt to use the scanner, it opens settings and asks if I want to allow the app to change system settings. If I check "yes", the scanner works but briefly returns an error. A minor bug that I will need to fix at some point. Let me know if you have any suggestions for fixing this. Thanks!